# Circle CI: is there a built-in way to run a job on modified files only?

Tags: python, circleci

I would like to setup a Circle CI job that runs the [black code formatter](https://github.com/psf/black) against **only the python files that were created or modified** in a PR, and leave the rest alone.

I know how to do this on my local terminal:

```
black $(git diff --name-only <target_branch_name>..<modifications_branch_name> -- '*.py')
```

From my research, it seems that doing this with Circle CI is not as simple because:

1. a normal `git diff` on a Circle CI environment [returns nothing](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/cant-get-git-diff-on-circleci-job/37644)
2. the target branch name is not present in the [built-in env vars](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#built-in-environment-variables)

[This article](https://javorszky.co.uk/2019/03/11/set-up-circle-ci-to-run-phpcs-on-only-changed-files-in-a-pr/) shows how one can set this up (very complicated procedure), but I wanted to ask if anyone knows how I can do this in a simpler way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look into

Dynamic Config https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config

A bit less straightforward, but not complicated, should allow you to do what you want!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32504708)